# How can I write a script to use an application

Tags: audio, automation, executable, volume, ableton-live

I am trying to write a script to edit multiple audio files.

I want to check each one for its volume level and increase it to its maximum if it is not at it. If I cant use a script, my best bet is to use Ableton Live to individually increase the volume which would take an extremely long amount of time given the amount of files I have.

I wold like to know if its possible to edit the volume in a script or programmatically use Ableton without having to manually increase the volume on each audio file.

If there is any advice on any of these options, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Addcode examples and clarify your problem giving reference to the codes

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to batch process audio files, and don't really need to program anything.
Many free options out there. Ableton might not be best suited for this...

Drag the files into arrangement view... *Pray it does not chrash*.
They will be one long track. Hold cmd / ctrl? for individual tracks.

You can add Compressor and adjust Threshold and Makeup Gain to adjust Volume.

Or, when you Export Audio, render individual tracks and check 'Normalize'.
Loudest option, possibly too much.